# Configuring cascade delete with EF7

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to configure a cascade delete using EF7 in a ASP.NET vNext application but I cannot find how to do it.

I'm overriding `OnModelCreating` and I have this code:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
              .OneToMany<Category>( e => e.SubCategories )
              .ForeignKey( e => e.ParentCategoryId );
```

The generated migration looks like this:

```
    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey("Category", "FK_Category_Category_ParentCategoryId", new[] { "ParentCategoryId" }, "Category", new[] { "Id" }, cascadeDelete: false);
```

Anyone know in what namespace the extensions to configure the cascade delete are defined?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you set cascadeDelete: true in the generated migration code ?

Comment: I could but would this be turned off every time I add a new migration?

Comment: No, you'll have a migration code for each migration, so you can edit the generated code safely, it will not be overriden by a new migration

Comment: Ok... But isn't there a way to do this with ModelBuilder? To me, this is more like a workaround than a clean solution. Is this feature already implemented in EF7?

Comment: This is not yet implemented, work is being tracked here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/333

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to find the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Promoting comment from lukew to an answer...

> This is not yet implemented, work is being tracked here github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/333