# EntityFramework Core 2.0.1 - Cascade Delete with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, .net-standard-2.0

I know this question has been asked and answered a few times:

[Specifying ON DELETE NO ACTION in Entity Framework 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768976/specifying-on-delete-no-action-in-entity-framework-7)

[Configuring cascade delete with EF7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800940/configuring-cascade-delete-with-ef7)

But in my case I'm using SQLite and none of the solutions seem to work. Similar code to update the database works in EF6 on SQL Server, but unless I'm missing something really obvious, doesn't work on EF Core with SQLite on .NET Standard 2.0. I have a parent Customer with child Contacts and am saving them all at once.

```
using (var dbc = new ContactsDbContext())
{                
    var customer = dbc.Customers.First(s => s.CustomerID == ReadProperty(CustomerIDProperty).ToString());

    foreach (var item in dbc.Contacts.Where(x => x.CustomerID == ReadProperty(CustomerIDProperty).ToString()))
    {
        dbc.Contacts.Remove(item);
    }
    MapToEntity(customer);
    dbc.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get the following exception upon SaveChanges()

System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The instance of entity type 'Contact' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value 'ContactID:99b44b3e-c981-4140-9198-b665d3d85600' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I loved having the ability to turn off cascade deletes globally in prior versions of EF. This is what used to work:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
}
```

And I've tried using these two solutions below, of which neither works for SQLite.

```
   foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
{
    // Also tried Cascade, and all other options
    relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
}
```

AND

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.Contact>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Customer)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey("CustomerID")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Has anyone successfully used parent/child updating on SQLite? My alternative is to manually check the status on each child object before saving, but that seems unnecessary for a feature that used to work. Thanks in advance for looking at this.
[image]

Here's my Contact and customer classes

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Contacts.Library.Data.Entity
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Contact
    {
        [Key]
        public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(36)]
        public string ContactID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CustomerID"), MaxLength(36)]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Path back to related customer
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
}

    [Serializable()]
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(36)]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // A customer has a collection of contacts
        public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
```

And here's my indexes

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Name on customer is unique
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.Customer>().HasIndex(c => c.Name).IsUnique();

        // Add index
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.Customer>().HasIndex(
            customer => new { customer.CustomerID }).IsUnique(false);

        // Add index
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.Contact>().HasIndex(
            contact => new { contact.ContactID }).IsUnique(false);

        // Add index
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.Contact>().HasIndex(
            contact => new { contact.CustomerID }).IsUnique(false);

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the actual exception message? Because the posted one has nothing to do with SQLite, cascade delete and `SaveChanges` - it should be thrown from some other method like `Attach`, `Add`, `Update`, `Remove` etc.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I've attached a screen grab of the exception.

Comment: That's really strange. Do you have custom code overriding `SaveChanges`? Also can you post the exception stack trace in order to get some clue what's going on?

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Nope, no overrides either. I copied my customer and contact classes into the post, as well as the OnModelCreating to show the indexes. What I've ended up doing is using an int ID on each one that I don't use, and it works. No idea why. The CustomerID and ContactID are unique Guid's. I tried the same with just integers and had the same result.

Comment: Do you see any `SELECT` queries running when `SaveChanges` is executed? It looks like the Sqlite query provider is trying to fetch data from the database while saving changes. Whatever it does, this looks like a serious bug.